# Left space between two texts (Dynamic)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, arrays

```
const Btn = () => {

    const options = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

    return (
         <div style={{ position: 'absolute', left: '8px', widht: 'auto', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', backgroundColor: '#006C84' }}>
            {options.map(opt => (
                <span style={{ paddingRight: '10px' }}>{opt}</span>)
            )}
         </div>
     )
    }
```

Above is my code and after the end of the text, there is some extra space are left. How to remove that space.

[image]

Comment: You are setting `padding-right: 10px` to all the spans, so the last one has that padding too. I would suggest you to use `flex` + `gap` for that - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: Example - https://play.tailwindcss.com/giNoy0UVbl

Comment: @ericmp
Above example with not worked as we have given padding right to child span,
see this example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/e1s3sm3FaV

Comment: Hey I am also facing same issue but with react-native but it's not working (gap is not working). 
So, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @DhavalParmar
can you share code snippet link which you are using for the react-native so i can get idea about it.

Comment: @PrashantShah I think you didn't understand me. I meant to remove the padding right, and use flex + gap instead. It's easy.

Comment: @PrashantShah Here I left my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73404514/how-can-i-add-space-inbetween-text-as-in-react-native-gap-css-is-not-working when you get time can you please check ?

Comment: @ericmp
Oh!, my bad i got your point what you are saying you are correct! Though i think padding right or margin right will be better way as gap prop is not support for some of the legacy browser

Comment: @DhavalParmar
I saw your question and it's been already answered

Comment: Check my answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/73405064/14272323) on this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73404514/how-can-i-add-space-inbetween-text-as-in-react-native-gap-css-is-not-working/73405064#73405064)

Answer (score 1):

So you are giving paddingRight: 10px to the span, so at the end of the last child it's showing some space left.

There are two ways you can achive this

1. JS way
2. Css way

**JS way**

```
{options.map((opt,index) => (
        <span style={{ paddingRight: options.length - 1 === index ? '10px' : "0px" }}>{opt}</span>)
   )}
```

**Css way**
you need to change the inline style to explicit style for this, I would say this is the recommended way of giving css over inline style or may be you can create one style object for that.

```
  <div className="parent">
        {options.map(opt => (
            <span style={{ paddingRight: '10px' }}>{opt}</span>)
        )}
     </div>

.parent{//parent css goes here}
.parent span:not(::last-of-type){padding-right: 10px}
```

Comment: Thanks @Prashant Shah for your response I know with js Way but a little bit confused with CSS Way.

Comment: Welcome @Abhi , I hope your doubts on CSS part is clear now. also if you feel then please mark answer as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  const Btn = () => {

    const options = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

    return (
         <div style={{ position: 'absolute', left: '8px', widht: 'auto', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', backgroundColor: '#006C84', display: 'flex', gap: '10px' }}>
            {options.map(opt => (
                <span>{opt}</span>)
            )}
         </div>
     )
   }
```

use display: flex and gap inside the parent div style

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-ganguly-kl4ys7?file=/src/App.js