# How can I add space Inbetween text as in react native gap css is not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, sass

Here I want space between test1 and test2.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  const data = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      {data.map((text) => (
        <span style={styles.span}>{text}</span>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    marginTop: 30,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    left: "8px",
    widht: "auto",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  span: {
    gap: 20
  }
});

export default App;
```

But currently it look like this

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-sea-tlbjso?file=/src/App.js
How can I achive this through css ?

###### Updated------------------------------------------------------

if I add marginRight in span then it will add extra space at the end of the text.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the gap property alongside display: flex inside the class app.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

function App() {
  const data = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      {data.map((text) => (
        <span>{text}</span>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    marginTop: 30,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    left: "8px",
    width: "auto",
    flexDirection: "row",
    display: "flex",
    gap: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  }
});

export default App;
```

[image]
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-chebyshev-22kuqd?file=/src/App.js:0-573

Comment: Hi @Gelo Chang in codesandbox it's working fine but little bit confused why it's not working while testing in emulator / Physical device. 
Can you please suggest any other way we can gave space in-between texts ?

Comment: The Gap property is not working in react native is that the case ?

Comment: Did you do the same thing as what I did above?

Comment: Yes, @Gelo Chang

Comment: Can you inspect the element maybe something overwriting it?

Comment: React Native does not yet support the gap property. It seems, as per https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/pull/3398, that the gap property will be released in react-native 0.71, that is not yet released, but should be released soon: https://github.com/reactwg/react-native-releases/discussions/41#discussioncomment-4610570